# Can't properly build HttpUrl which contains hash-bang

Tags: okhttp

I'm trying to build `HttpUrl` instance which contains hash-bang but can't properly do so. Final URL string value should look like this example: `https://www.google.com/mobile/#!/id?platform=android`

I've tried few solutions:

1. https://gist.github.com/novachevskyi/71529d8fdecf120e626af227193a9e0f
   When adding hash-bang with `HttpUrl.Builder::addEncodedPathSegment` then final result would contain encoded hash symbol.
2. https://gist.github.com/novachevskyi/12b59e53d6162fb1cd4e6236b03fb504
   After parsing base URL which contains hash-bang I'm getting next result:
   `https://www.google.com/mobile/?platform=android#!/id`

Is there any way to build `HttpUrl` instance were string value would contain hash-bang in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `.parse()` or with `.fragment()`.

```
HttpUrl a = HttpUrl.parse("https://www.google.com/mobile/#!/id?platform=android");
HttpUrl b = new HttpUrl.Builder()
    .scheme("https")
    .host("www.google.com")
    .encodedPath("/mobile/")
    .fragment("!/id?platform=android")
    .build();
```

Comment: Also note that `/id` is not a path segment, and `platform=android` is not a query. Any resemblance to that is just coincidental.